# Can you declare a PHP variable one scope up?

Tags: php, function, parameters, scope

**GOAL: Declare/set variables in the scope of the function that called the running function.**

**DETAILS:**
Hey Overflowans,

I'm looking to add one last little piece of sugar to a utility that I use in a lot of my php functions. It allows me to define a flexible contract on the input of my functions. Over a few iterations, I've gotten it pared down to a usage that looks like this:

```
function doSomething($param_arr){
    FPX::contract(array(
        'required' => array("length", "width", "height", "weight"),
        'optional' => array("circumference")
    ));
    $length = $parr['length'];
    $width = $parr['width'];
    $height = $parr['height'];
    $weight = $parr['weight'];
    $circumference = $parr['circumference'];
    ....
}
```

FPX::contract() automatically grabs the $param_arr and parses it to make sure that it's compatible with the defined contract.

What I would like to do now is eliminate the need to declare each of the variables afterwards. Is there a way that I can, within the lowest function, declare variables in the scope of the function that called it? So FPX::contract() needs to be able to set variables that are in the scope of doSomething() so that I don't have to declare each of these variables. (I don't want to declare globals).

Ideally it would just look like:

```
function doSomething($param_arr){
        FPX::contract(array(
            'required' => array("length", "width", "height", "weight"),
            'optional' => array("circumference")
        ));
    ....
}
```

And then doSomething() would be able to access each of the variables listed in the contract as $length, $width, etc.

I'm aware of the function($var0, $var1, $var2=null) syntax, but it's not very easy to use this syntax with a large number of optional variables.

Thanks,
Ken

Comment: You could try using `$var = "nameOfVar"; $$var = $value;` to set arbitrary named variables. Keep security in mind though!

Comment: this doesn't declare them a scope up though. it declares them in the scope of FPX::contract

Comment: D'oh, should've thought of that! Time for bed I think...

Comment: anyone want to explain the -1? would be nice to know why you think this is worthy of a downvote, else i'm not learning much.

Comment: Not sure why anyone would downvote this. I've +1'ed to counteract.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you can do something with [extract()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php)?

That is, just have your contract() return an array or a reference to an array, then extract() it.

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like

```
extract(FPX::contract(array(
        'required' => array("length", "width", "height", "weight"),
        'optional' => array("circumference")
    )));
```

Its slightly different from the idea you had about it, but the result should be, what you expected.

```
extract(array('foo'=>'bar'));
echo $foo;
```

http://php.net/extract

Comment: that's cute. if possible, I'd like to keep it inside the FPX::contract function though. this solution is definitely clever, but less clean, no?

Comment: No, its not possible. However, if you ask me, even accessing variables, that are _not_ given as parameters (or properties of the class/object, or a class/object the method has direct access to) is not very clean (too much magic and such). Using `extract()` on the return value is at least not that dirty ;) In my eyes, when a function/method requires 4 parameters, make 4 parameters, or maybe a value object (class) and don't use a generic array

Comment: fair enough. to me, it would be cleaner to have it all encapsulated in one function, instead of having to write the two chained together. as for the cleanliness of hiding params, it's super helpful for high level functions that manage searches with lots of options. if a function has many params and more than one optional one, it gets difficult to call. passing in a class for the params is probably how i should be doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Do they have to be a collection of variables and not an associative array?

```
$parsedParams = FPX::contract(array(
    'required' => array("length", "width", "height", "weight"),
    'optional' => array("circumference")
  ),
  $param_arr
);

echo $parsedParams['length'];
echo $parsedParams['circumference'];
```